# How can one conquer sleep ? Who is the god of sleep?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, sleep

How can one conquer the sleep ? Who is the God of sleep ?

Arjun is known to have conquered the sleep . How did he do it ?

Comment: Maa bhagavati is god of sleep, she was prayed to wake up bhagwan narayan from yog nidra.

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Thanks. But who is Maa Bhagvati , wiki tells that all three trivedevis are Bhagvati ? Also can you cite the reference to the story.

Comment: yes Bhavati is just striling of bhagwan, The reference is Shridurgasaptashati of markandeya puran

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow In this story which of the three Bhagvatis was prayed ?

Comment: There is only one, no three. That was the specific reason for writing no name

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow I can't get you . Aren't Laxmi , Parvathy and Saraswati three persons ? Parvathy's husband is Shiva , Laxmi's husband is Vishnu , while Parvathy is sister of vishnu . How can they be the same person ?

Comment: Why not they be same, there is only one feminine. They all can be seen different forms of devi. Anyway in the stuti she is addresssed as purnabrahma

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow But Parvathy is sister of Vishnu. And Laxmi is wife of Vishnu. How can one's wife and one's sister be the same person ?

Comment: Are Hari and hara different? Is mother Parvati different from bhagwan shiva?